# Live video stream web cam aggregator

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, red5, flash-media-server

I need to aggregate several live streams from web cams.
Then generate a single live stream for the client.

I see several apps to capture the web cam stream, but nothing that will splice the streams together.

Comment: Define 'splice'.  Do you mean you want them in a 2D grid?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to show 4 feeds in a new single feed tiled 2 x 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the OVERLAY filter.  To do a 2X2 tile screen you'll need to cascade multiple overlay filters.  Consult the documentation on Filter Graphs to simplify your command line arguments.